# How to mirror card placement over network

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

[image]

I'm not sure what logic I can use to place each card in the correct position. Example, I place in my middle drop zone (AllyDropZone (2)) and it appears the opposite way for my opponent (EnemyDropZone (2)). Right is (Host+client) and left is just a client.

Class `DropZone`:

```
public class DropZone : NetworkBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public int row;
    public int col;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();

        if (d != null)
        {

            if (CanDropCard(d))
            {
                d.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;
                Debug.Log(d.gameObject.name + " was dropped on " + gameObject.name);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Cannot drop " + d.gameObject.name + " on " + gameObject.name + ". Incorrect placement.");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CanDropCard(Draggable draggable)
    {
        // Checks to see if the card can be dropped on this spot
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("AllyDropZone") && draggable.isOwned)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Class `PlayerManager`:

```
public class PlayerManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    //Start of all network shared objects & variables//
    public GameManager GameManager;
    public GameObject PlayerCard;

    //All ally objects
    public GameObject AllyDropZone;
    public GameObject AllyDropZone1;
    public GameObject AllyDropZone2;
    public GameObject AllyDropZone3;
    public GameObject AllyDropZone4;
    public GameObject AllyHand;
    public GameObject AllyDeck;
    
    //All enemy object
    public GameObject EnemyDropZone;
    public GameObject EnemyDropZone1;
    public GameObject EnemyDropZone2;
    public GameObject EnemyDropZone3;
    public GameObject EnemyDropZone4;
    public GameObject EnemyHand;
    public GameObject EnemyDeck;

    //Lists that will hold ally and enemy drop zones resepctively
    public List<GameObject> AllyDropZones = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> EnemyDropZones = new List<GameObject>();

    //Possible alternative Card List; same purpose but better way of getting it
    private List<GameObject> cards = new List<GameObject>();

    //Card list we are pulling from
    public static List<Card> cardList = new List<Card>();

    //Variable tracking current player
    public bool IsMyTurn = false;

    //Variables that are constantly kept synced across the network; Think seeing health all the time
    //Need to be used later combat system 
    [SyncVar]
    int CardsPlayed = 0;
    int Health = 20;

    //End of declaration//


    //Start of actual code//

    //Runs the code below when Host+Client/Client button is selected
    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        base.OnStartClient();

        GameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

        //Connects hand and deck of both players to a variable by looking for objects with listed name 
        AllyHand = GameObject.Find("AllyHand");
        AllyDeck = GameObject.Find("AllyDeck");
        EnemyHand = GameObject.Find("EnemyHand");
        EnemyDeck = GameObject.Find("EnemyDeck");

        //Connects each ally drop zones to each variable by looking for objects with listed name 
        AllyDropZone = GameObject.Find("AllyDropZone");
        AllyDropZone1 = GameObject.Find("AllyDropZone (1)");
        AllyDropZone2 = GameObject.Find("AllyDropZone (2)");
        AllyDropZone3 = GameObject.Find("AllyDropZone (3)");
        AllyDropZone4 = GameObject.Find("AllyDropZone (4)");

        //Connects each enemy drop zones to each variable by looking for objects with listed name 
        EnemyDropZone = GameObject.Find("EnemyDropZone");
        EnemyDropZone1 = GameObject.Find("EnemyDropZone (1)");
        EnemyDropZone2 = GameObject.Find("EnemyDropZone (2)");
        EnemyDropZone3 = GameObject.Find("EnemyDropZone (3)");
        EnemyDropZone4 = GameObject.Find("EnemyDropZone (4)");

        //Fills Ally list with ally drop zones
        AllyDropZones.Add(AllyDropZone);
        AllyDropZones.Add(AllyDropZone1);
        AllyDropZones.Add(AllyDropZone2);
        AllyDropZones.Add(AllyDropZone3);
        AllyDropZones.Add(AllyDropZone4);

        //Fills Enemy list will enemy drop zones
        EnemyDropZones.Add(EnemyDropZone);
        EnemyDropZones.Add(EnemyDropZone1);
        EnemyDropZones.Add(EnemyDropZone2);
        EnemyDropZones.Add(EnemyDropZone3);
        EnemyDropZones.Add(EnemyDropZone4);

        //Determines which player goes first; Whoever presses "Client" button goes first
        if (isClientOnly)
        {
            IsMyTurn = true;
        }

        //Message to show that client is running; appears in console tab
        Debug.Log("OnStartClient was activated");
    }

    //Starts server (Host + Client)
    [Server]
    public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        base.OnStartServer();

        //Adds a card to current card list
        cardList.Add(new Card(0, "Jester", 1, 1, 2, "+1 power for every other Jester card on the board", Resources.Load<Sprite>("placeHolder")));
        
        //Should output current card list to console
        Debug.Log(cardList);

        //Tells us that the server is running
        Debug.Log("OnStartServer was activated");
    }

    //Command that adds cards to players hands and grants authority
    [Command]
    public void CmdDealCards()
    {
        //Fills player's hand with a card and repeats 3 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            GameObject card = Instantiate(PlayerCard, new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(card, connectionToClient);

            //Tells which card has been drawn
            Debug.Log("Drawing card" + i);

            //Sets current status of the card to "Dealt" which makes it appear in hand for the Server
            RpcShowCard(card, "Dealt");
        }

        //Changes game manager current state
        RpcGMChangeState("Compile");
    }

    //Calls upon CmdPlayCard
    public void PlayCard(GameObject card)
    {
        CmdPlayCard(card);
    }

    //Calls upon RocShowCard
    [Command]
    void CmdPlayCard(GameObject card)
    {
        RpcShowCard(card, "Played"); //Sets current status of the card to "Played" which makes it appear in a drop zone for the Server
    }

    //Actual function that moves the recently added card to hand and/or drop zone
    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcShowCard(GameObject card, string type)
    {
        if(type == "Dealt") // "Dealt" cards are placed into player's hand and checking ownership allows for it mirror
        {
            if (isOwned)
            {
                card.transform.SetParent(AllyHand.transform, false);
            }
            else
            {
                card.transform.SetParent(EnemyHand.transform, false);
            }
        }
        else if(type == "Played") // "Played" cards are placed into a player's drop zone and check mirror condition
        {
            if (isOwned)
            {
                //card.transform.SetParent(AllyDropZone.transform, false);
            }
            else
            {
                //card.transform.SetParent(EnemyDropZone.transform, false);
            }
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcGMChangeState(string stateRequest)
    {
        GameManager.ChangeGameState(stateRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather simple solution for 2 players, but can be used for any number of players with a small tweak.

Alice and Bob are playing. The game logic states: Alice got a card. This card arrives with that information at both clients. When we check that on Alice client, we know it is our card and place it on AllyHand, AllyDeck, AllyDropZone, etc. On Bobs client, have the same information but since Bob knows it is Alice card, his PlayerManager places it on the corresponding EnemyDrop location.

If you have more players, just use numbers for the location. Assign yourself the number 1 (or whichever number is in front of you). The server is providing a list of all players and in which order they are going. Find yourself on that list. Your player manager assigns the number 2 to the player after you in that list. Location 3 the player after. Continue until all locations are done. Now when the server sents information like: Player 3 gets a card, you make a lookup in your list which location you assigned to Player 3. Since that happens on each client, everyone can have the place in front of them for themself and the cards are placed visually correct in play order.

You should as well not use GameObject.Find("XYZ") for all those locations, since your GameObjects are already public, just assign them in the editor.